# Kendo Treelist reload/refresh after inline update

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I want to update data using kendo-tree-list and all works fine but the updated data doesn't refresh the content to new data.after a manual reloading of the page results in newly updated data into the tree-list and is there any way I can get a popup before deletion when I click delete, as far as now I can't find anything about that

i used

```
var grid10 = $("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList");
grid10.dataSource.read();
grid10.refresh();
```

for refreshing but nothing happened

Comment: Can you reformulate your question? Can't get your point here.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown when i fire the update after make proper changes,the row just disappearing but the data is updated when i reload the page

Comment: Can you create a working demo of your code?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand, you object name is wrong

Try this:

```
$("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList").dataSource.read();
```